# Is "learning", used as a noun, Denglish?

Tags: language-evolution

The English term "learning" is being used as a noun in German language, describing the process of learning something about a specific topic. ("Das Learning war, kein Wasser ins brennende Fett zu schütten." / "The learning was to not put water into the burning grease."). Is this a case of Denglish?

Comment: I think normally in English we could call it the "lesson learned".

Comment: "Learning" can be used as a noun in English (e.g. "a man of great learning") but the example in this question does sound wrong to me.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20learnings%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence

> The learning was to not put water into the burning grease

is unnatural in English. Or  it's obsolete. The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) reports that *learning* was once used to refer to

> What is learnt or taught:
>   a. a lesson, instruction.

But not anymore. So,   yes,  your sentence is Denglish.

Today we would probably say *the lesson learned* or *the lesson*:

> The lesson (or: lesson learned)  was to not put water into the burning grease.

However, we can use *learning* as a verbal-noun. The main definition is

> The action of receiving instruction or acquiring knowledge (OED)

This is close to your description "the process of learning something about a specific topic."

as in

> The learning of German is a hard and tortuous endeavor.

But we would probably use it more often without an article:

> Learning German is an arduous task.

*Learning* can also refer to

> Knowledge, esp[ecially] of language or literary or historical science, acquired by systematic study; also, the possession of such knowledge, learnedness. (OED)

For example, Alexander Pope wrote

> A little Learning is a dang'rous Thing. (OED)

Today we sometimes say a person knows  just enough about [some topic] to be dangerous.

Comment: After doing some checking around, it would seem that the type of Denglisch used here falls loosely under the category of pseudo-angliscism: a word borrowed directly but generally having a different meaning or usage in English.

Comment: @Cascabel yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking whether it is used the same way in English, then the answer is no.  If you'd like a comparable idiom in English:

***take-home message***

The use of *learning* as you described in German reminds me of the word for parking lot in France: "parking".

Comment: Or indeed how Germans use _Handy_ to mean ‘mobile phone’.

Comment: One thing to note is that that usage of the word has just appeared I'd say about two or three years ago. First it was used in business-speak and has since made its way into common language and even mainstream media.

Comment: @jbxbergdev - That might be interesting on German SE, but I think here our focus is supposed to be on usage in English.